# Facebook Group invite via Graph API

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I about to built a little online game in Action Script 3. At the moment everything is working pretty fine and there is just one thing left to do that makes me going crazy. After every Level of the Game the user should notified about his success and in case that the success was good enough, the user should be invited to a facebook group. At the Moment i have got an Facebook App, Authentification and Authorisation are working and what still is to manage is the invitation itself.
Does anybody know if there is a way to make this happen, and if so, how could it be done? Thanks a lot for a reply!

greetings!

Answer (score 0):

So, after having a nice day of »facebook api investigation« i would sum up the things i found out:
I'm quite sure that there is no way to make an group invitation via the graph api. The best result i could reach was an Error that told me: »requires the manage_groups permission«.

Consequently I added this permission to the login method and »tada«: the app didn't work anymore, just told me that there is an error with the app and I should try later again.

The code for getting this great message looked like this:

FB.api( "//members","POST", { name : "user name" }, function( response ){
//the great error appears here in the response
} );

I also was looking for something in the facebook.connect api but could not find something related to the problem i tried to solve.
If there is anybody who knows something better to try, i would very interested.

Greeting Philipp

Comment: FB.api( "/groupid/members", ... )

Answer (score 0):

Looks like "manage_groups" is not available to the public, (yet?). I'm following [this](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/429197933786570) and [this](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/529689243723476) discussion about it, as "manage_groups" seems to be required to invite a user to a group, but is not listed in the Facebook reference of extended permissions.